# Is the FB PHP SDK's getAccessToken() a reliable way to retrieve a user's auth token?

Tags: php, javascript, session, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-oauth

So I have a FB app and in some situations I need my Javascript to load content into a div using a php file that lives in the same domain as index.php. For some of these I like to make sure that the user is still valid and/or have need of an auth token and FB user id. I achieved this by making creating an instance of the FB PHP SDK in the php file being ajax injected by the javascript and using getUser() and getAccessToken(). I have noticed, however, that sometimes inexplicably the getAccessToken() call will fail and report that it needs a valid access token to perform the action.

Is getAccessToken() a reliable (or even ideal) way to ensure a user is logged into FB or should I be doing something else (e.g. storing the access token I parse from the signed request in Javscript and passing it as a variable to the php files I am injecting)? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most reliable would probably be to get their details. I have, in hte past, had an instance of "getUser" return true, but the user has not actually logged on. So now I also get all their details and this works more reliably:

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
                            'appId' => FB_APP_ID,
                            'secret' => FB_APP_SECRET,
                            'cookie' => true
                    ));
$FB_UID=false;
try {
    $FB_UID = $facebook->getUser();
    // This verifies the user is actually logged in. teh above can return "true" but the following will crap out and throw exception
    $FB_me = $facebook->api('/me');  // 'birthday'
    // Not needed:
    // $FB_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();

} catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    $FB_UID = false;
    $FB_me = false;
    // $FB_token = false;
}
```

Comment: I see, and then I could just use the ->api() call do do things like delete a user's FB request without actually needing access to their access token?

Comment: Yes - you need the access token if you are not using the "cookie" parameter (or doing fancy things such as possing access token around, storing in a DB for later use etc). If that's the case, a) store the access token when the user has connected, use "setAccessToken()" when you want to use that access token, then use the above "getUser" and "api(/me)" code to check that access token is still valid.